# Are angles of a triangle always positive?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If a question says "$A,B,$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle".

Can I assume $A,B,$ and $C$ to be positive and its properties such as arithmetic mean greater equal to geometric mean?

Also angle sum property of triangle seems to look flawed. I think it should be about absolute value of angle a triangle add up to π rather than sum of angles of triangle add up to π. Or maybe I am missing something. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive" ? If the angle $\hat{ABC}$ is positive, $\hat{CBA}$ is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the terms *angle* and **oriented** *angle.*

Planar geometry generally don't use oriented angles, only "common" angles between $0$ and $2\pi.$

So you may assume angles of triangle as positive values in the interval $(0, \pi).$

Answer (score 0):

For angles, we have 4$\pi = 0$, so for example $3\pi = -\pi$. Thus, there is no natural way to talk about positive and negative angles. You can define it, but then you define a notation to stand for a positive and another notation for a negative angle, as this makes computation easier in some cases.
For triangles, we usually define that each angle should be between $0$ and $2\pi$, and thus they are always positive. There might be other definitions, e.g. when looking at angles in a triangle inside the unit circle, but again, these are just definitions useful in this particular case, it is never an overall property (of triangles).

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean geometry, angles are non-negative. This follows from whole-part postulate (the whole is greater than a part).

Answer (score 0):

Any triangle splits the plane in two region: the interior and exterior of the triangle. Generally an angle of the triangle is assumed to be the [internal angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles) between two sides. If not otherwise stated it assumed to be not oriented and thus positive.

> The size of a geometric angle is usually characterized by the magnitude of the smallest rotation that maps one of the rays into the other.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Measuring_angles